# Local Storage not Defined

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to use localstorage in javascript to save data between executions. Here is the code using it

```
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');
roasts = localStorage.getItem("roasts").split(/\r?\n/);

class RoastMe  extends commando.Command {
    constructor(client){
        super(client, {
            name:'addroast',
            group:'insult',
            memberName:'addroast',
            description:'Add a roast to the !roastme archive'
        });
    }

    async run(message, args){
        if(args.length==0) message.reply("That aint a roast.");
        else{
            roasts.push();
            roasts[roasts.length-1] = args;
            var save = "";
            for(var i = 0; i < roasts.length; i++){
                save += roasts[i] + "\n";
            }

            localStorage.setItem("roasts", save);
        }
    }
}
module.exports = RoastMe;
```

This is the error it produced when i tried to run it

```
ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
at Object.<anonymous>

//location of error
(/home/ubuntu/workspace/commands/insult/addinsult.js:2:1)

at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/require-all/index.js:52:46
at Array.forEach (native)
```

If there's a better way to store data between executions, please let me know. Otherwise, could you explain why this isn't working? 
Thanks.

EDIT: The code posted is from addinsult.js

Comment: This looks like server side code. `localStorage`, however, is a browser feature.

Comment: could you suggest another way to store data between executions?

Comment: save it in the session

Comment: ***where*** are you trying to store data between executions?  Is this in a webpage or in node.js or somewhere else?

Comment: Preferably in a text or json file in the same directory as this js file (/commands/insult)

Comment: This is in node.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you defining local storage? If it's a module you need to 'require' it.

this line `roasts = localStorage.getItem("roasts").split(/\r?\n/);`

Is trying to do stuff with something called "localStorage", which has never been defined.

It looks like you're trying to use this module if i'm not mistaken: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-localstorage I found these instructions on how to use it on that page.

```
if (typeof localStorage === "undefined" || localStorage === null) {
   var LocalStorage = require('node-localstorage').LocalStorage;
   localStorage = new LocalStorage('./scratch');
}

localStorage.setItem('myFirstKey', 'myFirstValue');
console.log(localStorage.getItem('myFirstKey'));
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to declare it somewhere, like in the top of the js file, specifying it is global:

```js
/* global localStorage, */
```

or, alternatively, use the version tied to window (it is your global object)

```js
window.localStorage.setItem("roasts", save);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe some there used

```
delete localStorage;
```

change to

```
localStorage.clear();
```