# Pass variables between different .js files; inside the same html file

Tags: javascript, html, scripting

can anyone help me to pass variables from one .js file to another one, the two .js are instantiated in the same html as following:

```
<script src="file_1.js"></script>

<script src="file_2.js"></script>
```

the content of "file_1.js" is like this:

```
var paragraph = readFile('file_to_read.tcl');
```

so what i need, is to use the "paragraph " variable in side the "file_2.js script

Great thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I access variables from another file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244361/can-i-access-variables-from-another-file)

Comment: Thanks Qrazier for the link

Answer (score 0):

You can save them locally like this:
file_1.js:

```js
window.paragraph = readFile('file_to_read.tcl');
```

file_2.js:

```js
setTimeout(function(){ //a small timeout to let the variable be declared...
  alert(window.paragraph);
}, 100);
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Yuvix/project/editor/AnGkRz)

Comment: Many thanks Yuval, do I need a specific environment to use this ? jut tested it in rhino & got this issue : "js: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: ReferenceError: "localStorage" is not defined."

Comment: This is weird... I'll take a look at this once I'm home.

Comment: Idk if this works but please try. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62113977

Comment: I have test it in [codepen](https://codepen.io/Yuvix/project/editor/AnGkRz) and it works just fine, perhaps the problem is with Rhino.

Comment: OK, I found another working solution, try it (I have also updated the codepen).

Comment: i see it works, Many thanks, but this one :"  window.paragraph = 'testttt';  "  should be replaced by "   window.paragraph = 'readFile('file_to_read.tcl') ';  "  to read the file to the variable named "paragraph"

Comment: I tested it: file_1.js:    
setTimeout(function(){ 
  window.paragraph = readFile('file_to_read.tcl');  
  localStorage.setItem("paragraph", paragraph);  
}, 100);     and got this error:  "TypeError: readFile is not a function"

Comment: This is already a problem with your code, this is what you wrote.