# Local Storage is null

Tags: javascript, null

I have two functions for writing and reading an base64Image String to the local Storage in Javascript, but when i read the value it always returns null

```
function savePic (files) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);

    reader.onload = function () {
        console.log(reader.result);
        localStorage.setItem("profilePic", "Teststring");
        console.log("stored in localstorage");
    };
    reader.onerror = function (error) {
        console.log('Error: ', error);
    };   
}

function getPic(){
    return localStorage.getItem("profilePic");
}
```

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015107/local-storage-not-defined) it might be a variable scope problem. Try defining it outside your functions as `global localStorage` or using `window.localStorage` instead. I would opt for the second personally.

Comment: Thx for your answer, but this does not seem to work

Comment: check in the Application tab for the domain of your storage, you might be setting to domain xxx and reading from yyy