# Javascript project won't build because of localStorage function

Tags: javascript, local-storage, vite, sveltekit

I am building a SvelteKit project and is being built using Vite. I have the following simple code in one of my Typescript files:

```
let db_exists_key = "database-exists"
let db_exists = localStorage.getItem(db_exists_key)

if (db_exists != "exists") {
    await initUnitsAndDimensions()
    await initCalculator()
    localStorage.setItem(db_exists_key, "exists")
}
```

In this code, i check if the program has run before:

- If the program has not run, then initialize the database with its schemas.
- If the program has run, then the database exists, and we do not want to initialize the database again.

I get the following error when trying to build:

```
node:internal/event_target:1033
  process.nextTick(() => { throw err; });
                           ^
ReferenceError [Error]: localStorage is not defined
    at path/to/project/.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/dimension.js:35:1
Emitted 'error' event on Worker instance at:
    at [kOnErrorMessage] (node:internal/worker:300:10)
    at [kOnMessage] (node:internal/worker:311:37)
    at MessagePort.<anonymous> (node:internal/worker:212:57)
    at [nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:757:20)
    at exports.emitMessage (node:internal/per_context/messageport:23:28)
```

The path `path/to/project/.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/dimension.js:35:17` leads me to the following line of code:

```
let db_exists = >localStorage.getItem(db_exists_key);
```

The error message mentiones localStorage is not defined. What could be the issue to this?

Comment: Only browsers have a localStorage.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015107/local-storage-not-defined

Comment: Im pretty sure the code is running in the browser?

Comment: It will run on the server and in the browser by default due to server-side rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing the question, i found the answer... [This post](https://developer.school/snippets/react/localstorage-is-not-defined-nextjs) explains the issue:

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    let db_exists_key = "database-exists"
    let db_exists = localStorage.getItem(db_exists_key)

    if (db_exists != "exists") {
        await initUnitsAndDimensions()
        await initCalculator()
        localStorage.setItem(db_exists_key, "exists")
    }
}
```

By wrapping the code inside `if (typeof window !== "undefined") { ... }`, it will...

> ensure that localStorage is defined before you attempt to access it.

---EDIT---

As HB mentioned, the `browser` variable from `$app/environment` works too:

```
import { browser } from "$app/environment";
if (browser) { ... }
```

Comment: The only way that window is undefined is if the code isn’t running in a browser

Comment: You can also use the [`browser` flag](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-environment-browser).